# OpenSSH SSH Server service hangs at `SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT` but works with `sshd`

Tags: windows, ssh

### To those coming here from Google and want to know how to work around this problem

```
C:\Users\Max> Stop-Service sshd
C:\Users\Max> sshd.exe -D
```

---

I've tried looking all over SO but can't find any question that is the same as mine.

I followed the [Microsoft instructions to installing OpenSSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell).  After running `Start-Service sshd` I attempted to run

```bash
ssh -v localhost
```

and it hung on `SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received`

```
C:\Users\Max> ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2 debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.  debug1: Connection established.  debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa type 0 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss type -1 debug1: identity file
C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1 debug1: Local version string
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'max\\max'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:
<implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
SHA256:siSz0AipzJDa/hJxhTiE7NzELkiFRpAAy9sDMIon+iA
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa RSA
SHA256:v27lapB5RWNHcmcWtRQViwtYCiDN1UOehYIxstP/uhY
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

#after a minute or so
Connection reset by ::1 port 22
```

I spent a while researching how to fix this to no avail.  This is the sshd_config I ended up with (commented out lines hidden)

```
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

.

However, something that **DOES** work was

```
Stop-Service sshd
sshd.exe -d
```

And in another terminal

```
C:\Users\Max> ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'max\\max'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:siSz0AipzJDa/hJxhTiE7NzELkiFRpAAy9sDMIon+iA
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:v27lapB5RWNHcmcWtRQViwtYCiDN1UOehYIxstP/uhY
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:v27lapB5RWNHcmcWtRQViwtYCiDN1UOehYIxstP/uhY
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Max/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
max\max@localhost's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
PowerShell 7.2.8
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
```

and back in the first terminal

```
C:\Users\Max> Stop-Service sshd
C:\Users\Max> sshd -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:qn9JBQDPZP8co34GMHXyAlC9/uRNBB7lHhMtMJAWIEU
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:siSz0AipzJDa/hJxhTiE7NzELkiFRpAAy9sDMIon+iA
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:lMjYaUInF9zYv8pHm+fa5gDhZVD55Kir1QMerAcmzx0
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
Connection from ::1 port 52290 on ::1 port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user max\\\\max service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: user max\\max matched group list administrators at line 87
debug1: userauth-request for user max\\\\max service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg rsa-sha2-512 pkblob RSA SHA256:v27lapB5RWNHcmcWtRQViwtYCiDN1UOehYIxstP/uhY [preauth]
debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
Failed publickey for max\\max from ::1 port 52290 ssh2: RSA SHA256:v27lapB5RWNHcmcWtRQViwtYCiDN1UOehYIxstP/uhY
debug1: userauth-request for user max\\\\max service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=max\\\\max devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user max\\\\max service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 3 failures 2 [preauth]
lookup_principal_name: User principal name lookup failed for user 'max\\max' (explicit: 1355, implicit: 1355)
Accepted password for max\\max from ::1 port 52290 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: max\\max has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: Not running as SYSTEM: skipping loading user profile
User child is on pid 36608
```

Success!!!

However, I want to know **how to make sshd work using the Windows Service** instead of manually doing sshd.